# Find waypoints along arcing path between two points with customizable apex height & distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I have a functioning script that creates an arc of waypoints for a cinemachine track between 2 gameobject(vector3's), I'd like to add a variable so that I can control the height of the arc as seen in this pic:
[image]

At the moment the method I have creates the arc based on a radius of the distance between the 2 points, I'd like to be able to control the height of the arc so that it calculates the points similar to the drawn line in the pic.  And to control where in the arc that maximum height occurs in relationship to the distance between posA and posB.

Here's the code I have for creating the arc as it is at the moment, which calculates the arc with a radius of half the distance between the 2 points:

```
static void CalcWaypoints(CinemachineSmoothPath path, Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB)
{
    int greenRingPointsNum = 8;
    float metersPerWaypoint = 10;
    //Here we calculate how many segments will fit between the two points
    int segmentsToCreate = Mathf.RoundToInt(Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / metersPerWaypoint);
    path.m_Waypoints = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint[segmentsToCreate + greenRingPointsNum];
    Debug.Log("Creating " + segmentsToCreate + " waypoints");
    
    
    // get circle center and radius
    var radius = Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / 2f;
    var centerPos = (posA + posB) / 2f;

    // get a rotation that looks in the direction of the target gameobject
    var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((posA - posB).normalized);

    for (var i = 0; i < segmentsToCreate; i++)
    {
        
        var angle = Mathf.PI * (i) / (segmentsToCreate + 1f);
        var y = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
        var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
        var pos = new Vector3(0, y, z);
        // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
        pos = centerDirection * pos;
        path.m_Waypoints[i] = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint();
        path.m_Waypoints[i].position = centerPos + pos;
    }

    //create a circle of points around the target gameobject at a give radius
    float greenRadius = 20f;
    int waypointNum = segmentsToCreate;
    for (int i = 0; i < greenRingPointsNum; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / greenRingPointsNum;
        Vector3 newPos = posB + new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * greenRadius, posB.y, Mathf.Sin(angle) * greenRadius);
        path.m_Waypoints[waypointNum] = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint();
        path.m_Waypoints[waypointNum].position = newPos;
        waypointNum++;
    }

}
```

Hope one of you great folks can help out :)

An Arc like the following pic, where I can control the height and it's distance between the 2 points:
[image]

Comment: No not parabolic,  I just want to create a smooth arc between the posA and PosB but be able to control it's maximum height

Comment: [Example](https://i.imgur.com/pW4MULj.png) of three potential arcs. hyperbolic, parabolic, hyperbolic (approximately)

Comment: Thinking about it again... a circular arc could reach arbitrarily high if you're interested in going the longer way around the circle :p Doubt that's what you're looking for though! [haha](https://i.imgur.com/mqtVDqY.png)

Comment: So I updated the question, yes I'd like to control in the arc where the maximum height will occur in relation to the distance between posA and posB, thanks for the link @Ruzihm, but the formulas just confused me, it's been 40 years, yes 40 since I did that kind of math in school :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be by dynamically making [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and then following them.

First, we define what direction the apex should be in, and find the apex:

```
float apexHeightFromA = 5f;  // apex is 5 world units above A
float apexDistanceFactor = 0.5f; // apex is halfway from A to B
Vector3 upDirection = Vector3.up; // direction apex is in relative to points

Vector3 aToB = posB - posA;
Vector3 flatAToB = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(aToB, upDirection);

Vector3 posApex = posA 
        + flatAToB * apexDistanceFactor
        + apexHeightFromA * upDirection;
```

Now, the Bézier curves can be defined. If we use two cubic Bézier curves, we will need two control points, one on either side of the apex. That is to say, one going toward point A and one going toward point B.

```
Vector3 controlPointApexA;
Vector3 controlPointApexB;
```

It's arbitrary how to define these. A good starting point might be going horizontally halfway to the end each control point is towards.

```
Vector3 apexToA = posA - posApex;
Vector3 apexToB = posB - posApex;

float controlPointDistanceFactor = 0.5f;

controlPointA = posApex 
        + controlPointDistanceFactor * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToA, upDirection);
controlPointB = posApex 
        + controlPointDistanceFactor * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToB, upDirection);
```

However we define the control points, we can proceed with the iteration along the curve.

First, we need to determine how many waypoints should come before vs after the apex. A reasonable assumption is for it to be reached according to its position between the points.

```
float apexTravelFactor = apexDistanceFactor;
```

Then, we can use the formula for a quadratic Bézier curve...

[image: Bézier curve formula]

... from A to apex or from apex to B depending on where we are in the curve.:

```
// cache for efficiency
Vector3 controlAToA = posA - controlPointA;
Vector3 controlBToB = posB - controlPointB;

Vector3 controlAToApex = posApex - controlPointA;
Vector3 controlBToApex = posApex - controlPointB;


for (var i = 0; i < segmentsToCreate; i++)
{
    float overallT = (float)i / segmentsToCreate;

    Vector3 control, controlToOrigin, controlToDest;
    float t;

    // are we going from a to apex or apex to b?
    if (overallT < apexTravelFactor)
    {
        // going from a to apex
        control = controlPointA;
        controlToOrigin = controlAToA;
        controlToDest = controlAToApex;

        t = overallT / apexTravelFactor;
    }
    else 
    {
        // going from apex to b
        control = controlPointB;
        controlToOrigin = controlBToApex;
        controlToDest = controlBToB;

        t = (overallT - apexTravelFactor) / (1f - apexTravelFactor);
    }

    Vector3 currentPos = control 
            + Mathf.Pow(1f - t, 2f) * controlToOrigin
            + Mathf.Pow(t, 2f) * controlToDest;
    
    path.m_Waypoints[i] = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint();
    path.m_Waypoints[i].position = currentPos;
}
```

---

Altogether, moving constants & such to the top:

```
static void CalcWaypoints(CinemachineSmoothPath path, Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB)
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONSTANTS & FACTORS
    // good candidates for [Serializable] fields
    // in a singleton and/or if this were not static 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    int greenRingPointsNum = 8;
    float metersPerWaypoint = 10;
    
    float apexHeightFromA = 5f;  // apex is 5 world units above A
    float apexDistanceFactor = 0.5f; // apex is halfway from A to B
    Vector3 upDirection = Vector3.up; // direction apex is in relative to points

    // can fiddle with to change "thickness" of curve
    float controlPointDistanceFactor = 0.5f;

    // can fiddle with to change how many waypoints come before vs after the apex
    float apexTravelFactor = apexDistanceFactor; 
    
    ////////
    // LOGIC 
    ////////

    Vector3 aToB = posB - posA;

    //Here we calculate how many segments will fit between the two points
    int segmentsToCreate = Mathf.RoundToInt(aToB.magnitude / metersPerWaypoint);
    path.m_Waypoints = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint[segmentsToCreate 
            + greenRingPointsNum];
    Debug.Log("Creating " + segmentsToCreate + " waypoints");
    
    Vector3 flatAToB = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(aToB, upDirection);

    Vector3 posApex = posA 
            + flatAToB * apexDistanceFactor
            + apexHeightFromA * upDirection;
    
    Vector3 apexToA = posA - posApex;
    Vector3 apexToB = posB - posApex;
    
    Vector3 controlPointA = posApex 
            + controlPointDistanceFactor 
            * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToA, upDirection);
    Vector3 controlPointB = posApex 
            + controlPointDistanceFactor 
            * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToB, upDirection); 
    
    Vector3 controlAToA = posA - controlPointA;
    Vector3 controlBToB = posB - controlPointB;
    
    Vector3 controlAToApex = posApex - controlPointA;
    Vector3 controlBToApex = posApex - controlPointB;
   
    for (var i = 0; i < segmentsToCreate; i++)
    {
        float overallT = (float)i / segmentsToCreate;
        // if you want to have waypoint at posB:
        // float overallT = (float)i / (segmentsToCreate-1);
    
        Vector3 control, controlToOrigin, controlToDest;
        float t;
    
        // are we going from a to apex or apex to b?
        if (overallT < apexTravelFactor)
        {
            // going from a to apex
            control = controlPointA;
            controlToOrigin = controlAToA;
            controlToDest = controlAToApex;
    
            t = overallT / apexTravelFactor;
        }
        else 
        {
            // going from apex to b
            control = controlPointB;
            controlToOrigin = controlBToApex;
            controlToDest = controlBToB;
    
            t = (overallT - apexTravelFactor) / (1f - apexTravelFactor);
        }
    
        Vector3 currentPos = control 
                + Mathf.Pow(1f - t, 2f) * controlToOrigin
                + Mathf.Pow(t, 2f) * controlToDest;
        
        path.m_Waypoints[i] = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint();
        path.m_Waypoints[i].position = currentPos;
    }
    
    //create a circle of points around the target gameobject at a give radius
    float greenRadius = 20f;
    int waypointNum = segmentsToCreate;
    for (int i = 0; i < greenRingPointsNum; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / greenRingPointsNum;
        Vector3 newPos = posB + new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * greenRadius, posB.y, 
                Mathf.Sin(angle) * greenRadius);
        path.m_Waypoints[waypointNum] = new CinemachineSmoothPath.Waypoint();
        path.m_Waypoints[waypointNum].position = newPos;
        waypointNum++;
    }    
}
```

For funzies, try setting a negative value for `apexHeightFromA`, and/or a value that would put the "apex" between the "heights" of `posA` and `posB`. You'll see that it should still look ok, although it certainly won't be an "apex" anymore ;)

---

If you want to preview the waypoints, see below:

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float apexHeightFromA = 5f;  // apex is 5 world units above A
    [SerializeField] float apexDistanceFactor = 0.5f; // apex is halfway from A to B
    [SerializeField] Vector3 upDirection = Vector3.up; // direction apex is in relative to points
    [SerializeField] Vector3 posA;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 posB;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        CalcWaypoints();
    }

    void CalcWaypoints()
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONSTANTS & FACTORS
        // good candidates for [Serializable] fields
        // in a singleton and/or if this were not static 
        //////////////////////////////////////////////

        // animate apex distance factor
        apexDistanceFactor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 0.3f, .8f) + 0.1f;

        float metersPerWaypoint = 10;

        // can fiddle with to change "thickness" of curve
        float controlPointDistanceFactor = 0.5f;

        // can fiddle with to change how many waypoints come before vs after the apex
        float apexTravelFactor = apexDistanceFactor;

        ////////
        // LOGIC 
        ////////
   
        Vector3 aToB = posB - posA;

        //Here we calculate how many segments will fit between the two points
        int segmentsToCreate = Mathf.RoundToInt(aToB.magnitude / metersPerWaypoint);
        Debug.Log("Creating " + segmentsToCreate + " waypoints");

        Vector3 flatAToB = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(aToB, upDirection);

        Vector3 posApex = posA
                + flatAToB * apexDistanceFactor
                + apexHeightFromA * upDirection;

        Vector3 apexToA = posA - posApex;
        Vector3 apexToB = posB - posApex;

        Vector3 controlPointA = posApex
                + controlPointDistanceFactor
                * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToA, upDirection);
        Vector3 controlPointB = posApex
                + controlPointDistanceFactor
                * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(apexToB, upDirection);

        Vector3 controlAToA = posA - controlPointA;
        Vector3 controlBToB = posB - controlPointB;

        Vector3 controlAToApex = posApex - controlPointA;
        Vector3 controlBToApex = posApex - controlPointB;

        for (var i = 0; i < segmentsToCreate; i++)
        {
            float overallT = (float)i / (segmentsToCreate + 1);
            // if you want to have waypoint at posB:
            // float overallT = (float)i / (segmentsToCreate-1);

            Vector3 control, controlToOrigin, controlToDest;
            float t;

            // are we going from a to apex or apex to b?
            if (overallT < apexTravelFactor)
            {
                // going from a to apex
                control = controlPointA;
                controlToOrigin = controlAToA;
                controlToDest = controlAToApex;

                t = overallT / apexTravelFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                // going from apex to b
                control = controlPointB;
                controlToOrigin = controlBToApex;
                controlToDest = controlBToB;

                t = (overallT - apexTravelFactor) / (1f - apexTravelFactor);
            }

            Vector3 currentPos = control
                    + Mathf.Pow(1f - t, 2f) * controlToOrigin
                    + Mathf.Pow(t, 2f) * controlToDest;

            Gizmos.DrawSphere(currentPos, 1f);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: example of code]

Comment: Absolutely perfect, I can't thank you enough @Ruzihm

Comment: @ChrisBanwell Interesting... maybe another typo in there. If you put a breakpoint at `control = controlPointB` what is the value of `apexTravelFactor`?

Comment: @ChrisBanwell hmm.... How many waypoints are being generated? does it work if you set `apexTravelFactor` to 0.5f? Also, did you say there were no waypoints being placed *before* or *after* the apex with `apexTravelFactor = 0.2f`?

Comment: Yeah I just tested it over longer distances betwen A and B, it seems the longer the distance the 'curve' seems to have the apex nearer the center given a value of 0.2f for the apexDistance from posA.  Although the posApex vectore appears in the correct place (I just spawned a cube at it).  The number of waypoints generated is dependent on the distance between A and B I create 1 every 10 meters at the moment.

Comment: @ChrisBanwell It works for me! [example](https://i.imgur.com/YKY4JZK.gif)

Comment: yes I think the only problem is the last waypoint at posB gets raised up, whereas the first waypoint at A stays at posA, for me it's not a problem :)  The last comment I added was caused by a typo from me this time :)  But I noticed the error too late to edit the comment

Comment: Ah, then do `float overallT = (i+1f) / (segmentsToCreate + 2);` instead :)

Comment: What would be really cool is to make it 3 dimensional, so if we then move either of the posA,posB or the apex position in the x plane, the curve would reflect that and re plot itself  essentially curving left to right if viewed from either end.  obviously it would require a new input of apex position, rather than it being calculated.

Comment: @ChrisBanwell I think it should work if you provide `posApex` and set `apexTravelFactor` to something appropriate